# how long does it take a truck to pass another?

Tags: calculus

Two trucks each $20m$ long travelling alongside each other at $60 km/h$. one truck (instantly) accelerates to $62km/h$.

How much distance and time will be covered before the faster truck passes the other completely?

Comment: I would say that the question is more appropriate for: physics.stackexchange.com You should probably try it there.

Comment: Is this some (fundamental) question to gain insight or just your physics homework?

Comment: It's a question I thought of whilst driving, wondering how long it takes for an articulated lorry took to pass as they so often do.

Comment: @Ziezi I don't agree. This has nothing to do with any principle or physical law. It's more appropriate to a site like this one.

Comment: @JeanMarie Length, speed and time are not only related to physics, but fundamental parts of it. The specific physics we are talking about here are the _equations of motion_ that describe the behaviour of the PHYSICAL system, related to the _Newton's second Law_, regardless of whether you agree or not.

Comment: @Ziezi I have no taste for polemics ; so I will stop there. Let me just observe that for example an "instant acceleration" is not very "physical".

Comment: @JeanMarie I will agree with you about the used terminology.

Comment: @Ziezi ....... :)

Answer (score 1):

The (relative) speed of the faster truck with respect to the slower truck is 2km/h. How long does it take for a car moving at that speed to go 20m? That is the time you are looking for. How far will a truck travelling at 60km/h travel in that time? That is the distance you are looking for.

Comment: That was my initial thought, the difference is 2kmph, but the fact they are both moving at speed makes me think that it is a factor to the time taken, and possibly the distance.

Comment: In short, you can look at a system from the side of the street, or on board of a vehicle moving at constant speed and "the physics" should be the same. This is called Galilean relativity, which is a small velocity limit of Special relativity. Serious time dilation happens only at speeds comparable to the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

In an hour he gets $2KM$ further, so to get $0.02KM$ further he needs $\frac{1}{100}$ of an hour, which is $0.6$ minutes, which is $36$ seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same result - 36 seconds, but i'm not confident of my workings, I really had to dust off that part of my brain!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is same as 76david76
.
The faster truck need 36 sec to cross the slower truck.
Therefore the slower truck travel a distance of 60×$\frac{1}{100}$=0.6km or 600 m.
That's all
.

Comment: Thanks - can you explain what the figures (60 1/100) represent in relation to the 36 seconds so I may get my head around it?

Comment: 36 seconds=1/100hour,since 1hour =60×60=3600 seconds

Comment: Also distance(km) =speed (in km/h)×time (hr)@jon  Johnson

Comment: Ah I think i get it, calculate the time first, then apply that to to the speed of the slower vehicle. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How much distance and time will be covered before the faster truck passes the other completely?

$t = 36.36s$ and $d = 626.11m$

---

Considering the [Galilean Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation), the question could be reduced to: how much time does it take to cover $20m$ if you travel with speed of $2km/h$.

First, let's convert the speed to $m/s$ so that all our variables are in the  *"same range"*, i.e. distance in meters, speed in m/s, time in seconds.

$$2 km/h \rightarrow 0.55 m/s$$

Then, the needed time is: $time = \frac{path}{speed} = \frac{20}{0.55} = 36.36 sec$

Travelling with (62 km/h) $v = 17.22m/s$ for $ t = 36.36s$, the truck will cover distance:

$$d = v.t = 17.22 * 36.36 = 626.11m$$

---